# Как конвертировать String в Int?

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит ключ,после чего он должен расшифроваться (поделиться на 19001)и получится строка состоящая из даты конца работы и id железа.Но у меня проблема,я не могу из string достать строку,ошибка переполнения,как я понимаю из за того что stoi() возвращает int,а у меня число намного больше.

```
bool checkKey()
{
    string strUserkey = "0";

    long long llUserkey;

    cout << "Введите ключ: ";
    cin >> strUserkey;

    try
    {
        llUserkey = stoi(strUserkey);
    }
    catch (invalid_argument)
    {
        cout << "Невалидный ключ";
        return 0;
    }
    if (llUserkey <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Невалидный ключ";
        return 0;
    }

    llUserkey /= 19001;

    cout << llUserkey;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: А как насчёт `stoll`?

Comment: да проблема в том что строка может быть еще длиннее,я думал записать в массив int[],но я не знаю как тогда это число состоящее из массива поделить на 19001

Comment: Ну запинайте его в массив, скажем, по 9 цифр, а потом поделите "в столбик". Или, если правилами не запрещено :) - какую-нибудь реализацию длинной арифметики, скажем, из boost'а...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

char s[100000];
int i, c, j, x, y, r, b = 19001;
vector<int> a;

int main() {

    // Считываем длинное число
    for(cin >> s, i = strlen(s) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        a.push_back(s[i] - '0');


    // Деление длинного на короткое
    for (c = 0, i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        long long cur = a[i] + c * 1ll * 10;
        a[i] = cur / b;
        c = cur % b;
    }

    // Удаляем лидирующие нули
    while (a.size() > 1 && a.back() == 0) a.pop_back();

    // Выводим результат
    for (i = a.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        cout << a[i];
}
```

[Результат.](https://ideone.com/ZPhqgL)